# XAMPP (Windows) backup MySQL Database Automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a batch file in Windows to backup a MySQL Database, i have tried this:

```
C:\xampp\MySQL\bin\MySQLDump –u root –p database_name –result-file=”C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MySQLDump.sql”
```

but i get an error saying:

```
Got error: 1044: Access Denied for user ``@`localhost` to database `?u` when selecting the database
```

Comment: Looks like a quoting problem to me.  Tried the whole command in quotes?

Comment: Try changing `”` to `"`. Those aren't real quotes.

Comment: Also you should have `--result-file`, not `–result-file`. You're probably copying this command from some website that tries to "neatly" format characters, but renders the code unusable. Try writing the whole command out by hand instead of copying and pasting, and be sure only to use real quotes and real dashes.

Comment: The error message "database `?u` suggests that the batch file isn't reading the command parameters accurately, either.  So all of Mike's suggestions but you may *still* need to take steps to ensure the intelligibility of the command statement ...

Comment: how do i add the password into the command line?

Comment: i have just changed to this: `C:\xampp\MySQL\bin\MySQLDump -u root –pPASSWORD-HERE mysql_table –-result-file="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MySQLDump.sql"` but its telling me i am not specifying a password

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem/error was to use one of these mysqldump commands:

mysqldump --opt --lock-tables=false -u USER -p DBNAME > dump.sql

mysqldump --opt --single-transaction -u USER -p DBNAME > dump.sql

http://alvinalexander.com/mysql/mysql-error-1044-access-denied-for-user-using-lock-tables

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me. 
Don't forget to replace values inside `{}` as you need

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u{username} -p{passwrod} database > {/backuppath}.sql
```

Completed guide can be found at here:

https://www.tectut.com/2016/04/automatically-backup-mysql-databases-on-windows/